# How do I use the input function when you type in a variable name, and want it to be an integer for calculations later?

Tags: python

I have a question. So I want to use the `input()` function in python, but whatever variable you input in the input when it runs, I want to be assigned as a variable and then you can use it as a calculation later. For example,

```
variable = input("What is your model? ")
array = [1,2,3,4]
k1234 = array[0]
math = str(variable) + 5
```

That's just a simple example of what I am trying to do. But when I run it, and when I get the prompt: "What is your model?", I type in k1234 but then when it tries to do the math calculation it throws me the error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'k1234'
```

In total, I basically have an array of 20 - 25 values, and have a variable assigned to each of the indices separately in the array, but when you type the variable in the input section, it doesn't recognize it as a integer later on and can't perform the calculation. Anyone have any suggestions? I don't have much experience with input().

Edit: The question "How can I read inputs as integers?" doesn't quite answer my question. I'm trying to get a function that you put a string into the input, will recognize the string as a variable that is defined later on to then be recognized as an integer which you can then use as a calculation later on. `:)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read inputs as integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-integers)

Comment: I looked over that article, and it was helpful! It wasn't quite what I was asking but it definitely helped with my understanding of how the input function works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
variable = input("What is your model? ")
array = [1,2,3,4]
k1234 = array[0]
math = str(variable) + 5
```

This is not working because when you ask for the user's input and the user types "k123", they are setting "variable" to the *string*  "k123". If you check the contents of "variable" you will see that it is 'k123'.

Another reason why this program doesn't work is because you are trying to add a string (variable) to an integer (5). To fix both problems, you may want to do something like this:

```
variable = input("What is your model? ") #sets the user's input to variable
array = [1,2,3,4]              #defining a list
if variable == "k1234":        #checks the contents of "variable"
    variable = array[0]        #if variable=="k1234" is true, this sets variable to the first item in the list array (which is 1)
math = int(variable) + 5       #int(variable) makes sure that the contents of this variable is an integer, then it adds the result with 5 and sets the answer to the variable "math".
print(math)
```

If you run this program, then the result will be 6.

Comment: Oh okay, that makes total sense. I'm going to do that. So what if I have like 20 variables that I want set to the specific index? Like I have an array of 20 values, but each value is equal to a new variable (e.g, k1234 = 1, k12345 = 2, k123456 = 3, etc.) Will I have to do an if statement for all of those variables defined by that array? For example: if variable == "k1234":
                                     variable = array[0]
                                 elif variable == "k12345":
                                    variable = array[1] ?